# OData AspNetCore support for long URLs useing $query is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, odata

As it is been pointed in [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/passing-odata-query-options-in-the-request-body/) article, with **$query** keyword you can solve the problem of long OData URLs after the version 7.5 of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData`.

but in my project(I'm using version 8.preview3) I tried the use this but I keep getting **404 not found** error.
Here are my working URL examples:

```
https://localhost:44346/odata/WFC/APost/
https://localhost:44346/odata/WFC/APost/?$select=id
...
```

but when I use a POST request with **$query** I receive 404 error:

```
    POST: https://localhost:44346/odata/WFC/APost/$query
    Content-Type: text/plain
    Request Body: $select=id
```

**I wonder if I have to add any code to enable the $query functionality !?**

Here are relevant pieces of my code :

```
     // version 8.preview3 of Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData code

     services.AddOData(
           opt => opt.AddModel("odata", GetEdmModel()).Select().Count().Filter().OrderBy().SetAttributeRouting(true));
    
    ...
    
     public IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
            {
                var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
                var s = builder.EntitySet<WeatherForecast>("WFC").EntityType;
                s.Collection.Action("APost");
                return builder.GetEdmModel();
            }
```

and the controller :

```
    [ODataRoutePrefix("WFC")]
    public class WeatherForecast2Controller : ODataController
    {
     ...
        [HttpPost]
        [EnableQuery]
        [ODataRoute("APost")]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> APost()
        {
            // this function just returns array of 10 WeatherForecast(s) . 
            ...
        }

    }
```

Comment: The repo for OData WebApi 8 preview is [here](https://github.com/OData/AspNetCoreOData) and unfortunately the latest changes merged to [OData WebApi 7.* repo](https://github.com/OData/WebApi) are yet to be replayed/applied. That is the reason for the behaviour/error you're observing.

Comment: @JohnGathogo  I switched to 7.5.4 but still have the same problem. Other than $query, $format is not working for both versions( 8 and 7)

Comment: I'll try to repro and revert...

Comment: @JohnGathogo any news?

Comment: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2414#issuecomment-780052614

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create a POST endpoint. The POST `.../$query` request should be translated to the GET endpoint.

However, you need to use the middleware:

```cs
// Startup.cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  app.UseODataQueryRequest();
}
```

For more info refer https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2414#issuecomment-1021571407.