# How do I configure OData to use a POST with /$query on an endpoint configured with ODataAttributeRouting? I'm getting a 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, odata

This is a follow-up to [OData AspNetCore support for long URLs useing $query is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65611721/odata-aspnetcore-support-for-long-urls-useing-query-is-not-working).

OData 8.0.4

In startup, I have `app.UseODataQueryRequest()`
My Controller looks like

```
[ODataAttributeRouting]
public class ODataQueryController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet] // not needed, it turns out
    [EnableQuery]
    [Route("Thing")]
    public IActionResult GetThings()
    {
        return Ok(ApplicationContext.Things);
    }
}
```

and my POST looks like

```
POST http://localhost:8080/api/odata/Thing/$query

Request Body: $select=Column
Content-Type: text/plain
```

and I get a 404

Comment: Where in startup did you add app.UseODataQueryRequest()? It seems it needs to be added before app.UseRouting()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing `app.UseODataQueryRequest()` *before* `app.UseRouting()` resolved this issue for me

Startup.cs:

```
...
app.UseODataQueryRequest();
...
app.UseRouting();
...
```

Comment: omg. thank you. can I venmo you a beer or something?